# MongoDB Aggregate and keep all values while setting an active key

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, lookup

I want all the values returned from "Items" and when there is a match I want "isActive" to be true.

```
exports.listUserItems = function (req, res) {

  // Aggregate results
  User.aggregate([{
      "$match": {
          "username": req.params.username
      }
  }, {
      "$lookup": {
          "from": "Items",
          "localField": "itemIds",
          "foreignField": "_id",
          "as": "items"
      }
  }, {
      "$unwind": {
          "path": "$items"
      }
  }, {
      "$project": {
          "item": "$items.item_name",
          "isActive": '1',
          "_id": 0
      }
  }], (err, result) => res.json(result));
};
```

What is the best way to go about accomplishing this?

I was going to return all the items and users items seperately, then compare them and object.value them etc. etc... that seems like overkill. Can it be done on the model side?

I'm unable to post the document structure because stackoverflow doesn't let me, but you should get the idea.

Edit:

User Document

```
{
    "username" : "anonuser",
    "items" : [ 
        ObjectId("5ba8345f1e56fe8e6caaaa07"), 
        ObjectId("5ba706d64e82292e72e9ae71")
    ]
}
```

Then I have an "Items" collection which has 3 documents like this.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ba706d64e82292e72e9ae71"),
    "item_name" : "Salary"
}
```

My expected json api output is to be.

```
[{"_id":"5ba706d64e82292e72e9ae71","item_name":"Salary","isActive":true},{"_id":"5ba8345f1e56fe8e6caaaa07","item_name":"Fulltime","isActive":true},{"_id":"5ba9af6c1e56fe8e6cab521e","item_name":"Advisor","isActive":false}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below aggregation

```
Items.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "users",
    "let": { "itemsId": "$_id" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$in": ["$$itemsId", "$items"] }}},
      { "$project": { "isActive": { "$literal": true }}}
    ],
    "as": "items"
  }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "isActive": {
      "$ifNull": [{ "$arrayElemAt": ["$items.isActive", 0] }, { "$literal": false }]
    }
  }},
  { "$project": { "items": 0 }}
])
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, some [explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem 
 can go a long way as it provides insight not only for the questioner but for readers in the future! +1

Comment: Thank you @chridam for your kind opinion. I have updated my answer. But sometimes I get sluggish to write explanation **:-)** because most of the people made same mistake and writing same thing again and again becomes sluggish.

Comment: This doesn't work. This shows all the info from the user document.

Comment: By looking at your code, how does it know where the item_name value is coming from?

Comment: @R3W Could you post sample collection from both the document and the sample output as well

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet No problem, edited original question at bottom.

Comment: @R3W Updated my answer

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet This is great, almost there. I still need it to show the ones that don't match. You know what I mean, I need it to list all the items in the items collection.

Comment: @R3W Could please let me know your mongodb version?

Comment: @R3W Updated my answer

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet Almost again, it doesn't find the matches though. lol. I'm asuming "testcollection2" is my "Users" collection?

Comment: @R3W yes it's users collection and I have tested this query with robomongo goving me expected output

Comment: Sorry for not understanding... "Let" is getting the id from the list of items and not the user right? The $items in the match section is the array of items from the user?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet I guess I don't have to use unwind or anything?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet this is what I get: [{"_id":"5ba706d64e82292e72e9ae71","item_name":"Fulltime","items":[{"_id":"5b997cf8082be41757b6d733","isActive":true}],"isActive":true},{"_id":"5ba8345f1e56fe8e6caaaa07","item_name":"Part-time","items":[{"_id":"5b997cf8082be41757b6d733","isActive":true}],"isActive":true},{"_id":"5ba9af6c1e56fe8e6cab521e","item_name":"Advisor","items":[],"isActive":false}]

Comment: @R3W Yes and that's what you wanted to get? Is it correct?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet Thanks for your help. I don't want the extra array in there. It's showing the user id every time as well. I just want this...  [{"_id":"5ba706d64e82292e72e9ae71","item_name":"Fulltime","isActive":true},{"_id":"5ba8345f1e56fe8e6caaaa07","item_name":"Part-time","isActive":true},{"_id":"5ba9af6c1e56fe8e6cab521e","item_name":"Advisor","isActive":false}]

Comment: @R3W Updated my answer

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet Thank you so much. The trial and error we went through actually helped me learn a lot. You're a god to me.